# How can I get cursor update notifications without a CursorAdapter?

Tags: android-contentprovider, android-cursor, contentobserver

I'm writing a `Fragment` that uses a loader to get a `Cursor` containing data about locations of various things on a map.  I've inherited code to sort these locations by distance from the device, or from a search location; distance metrics aren't something that's particularly easy to implement in SQL, so rather than use a `CursorAdapter` (as elsewhere) I'm loading the data once from the `Cursor` and then sorting it afterwards.

I have just one problem: when the web service returns a new set of locations (for example, on first load), the list isn't updating.  I've registered a `ContentObserver` on the `Cursor` and it *is* being hit when I call `notifyChange(...)` in the `ContentProvider`; it's just that the `Cursor` I've stored from the original load still has a count of zero.

The callbacks and the `ContentObserver` look like this:

```
private LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> mCallbacks = new LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>() {
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {  
        mLoaderCreated = false;
        mCursor.unregisterContentObserver(mObserver);
        mCursor = null;
    }
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
        if(cursor!=mCursor) {
            if(mCursor!=null)
                mCursor.unregisterContentObserver(mObserver);
            cursor.registerContentObserver(mObserver);
            mCursor = cursor;
            if(cursor.isClosed()) {
                getLoaderManager().restartLoader(mFragmentId, null, mCallbacks);
                return;
            }

        }
        mDataModel.populate(cursor);
    }
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        mLoaderCreated = true;
        triggerServicesFeed();
        CursorLoader cursorLoader = null;
        if(id == mFragmentId) {
            cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
                FerrariVertuContentProvider.SERVICES_URI,
                null, null, null,null);
        }
        return cursorLoader;
    }
};

private ContentObserver mObserver = new ContentObserver(null) {

    public void onChange(boolean selfChange, android.net.Uri uri) {
        onChange(selfChange);
    };

    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        if(mCursor.isClosed()) {
            mCursor.unregisterContentObserver(this);
            mCursor = null;
        } else {
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //mCursor still reports zero on first run
                    mDataModel.populate(mCursor);
                }
            });
        }
    };
};
```

I know `CursorAdapter` just updates when the `Cursor` updates, and the fact that I'm getting update events when I'd expect to makes me think this stage of the process, at least, is working.  How do I either get `mCursor` to give me the new data, or get a fresh `Cursor` representing the new data?